# ViewModel property is empty even after initializing it

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I have a program, where user is being asked for granting location permissions, location service. After that, in the ViewModel user current geo location should be saved in MutableLiveData. In other function these geo location should be displayed in console. Turns out, it is empty, somehow. Where I've made a mistake?

**ViewModel**

```
    fun location(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val testLocation = locationRequest.getCurrentLocation()
        testLocation.let {
            _location.postValue(mutableMapOf("lat" to (it?.latitude ?: 00.00),
                "lon" to (it?.longitude ?: 00.00)))
        }
    }
}
fun test(){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        println("TEST ELSE ${location?.values}")
    }
}
```

**this code is run after granting location permissions, and turning on location service**

Comment: You’re launching two separate coroutines. If you are calling `test()` immediately after `location`, then they are racing and you can’t be sure which will finish first.

Comment: @Tenfour04 after deleting coroutine in test function it still display empty property. I've tried to make the location function a coroutine property and wait until it finish to make sure to get the location but it doesn't work either. What could I do with it?

Comment: Deleting the coroutine in the test function *guarantees* that it will run first since it won’t have to be scheduled so there is no race, so your result makes sense. Coroutines are asynchronous. Typically, if you want to do a series of actions in order, you put them inside the same coroutine. Other options are to use reactive components like LiveData and StateFlow, or you could store the first coroutine Job in a property and `join()` it to wait for it in another coroutine.

Comment: The answers to this question might help you understand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o

Comment: I've managed to do it. Thank you for the help. Appreciate it.